# how to solve Data type BLOB can not be converted to varchar2

Tags: sql, type-conversion, blob, apex, varchar2

I have created in apex 5.1 a report with form in oracle apex 5.1 in which I have a BLOB column called 'LIEN'. And when I insert data in the table and run the application I get this error:

> Data type BLOB can not be converted to VARCHAR2!

How can this be solved?

Comment: what is the type of BLOB in the DB and what type of data you are trying to insert as a value of that column?

Comment: i'm trying to insert a pfd file, but when i open the report i get the error above

Comment: @YOUCEFsami I know this is old question, but did you resolved this in another way then changing the column to Clob? I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Blob` is used for binary data, like image or other binary files.

For textual long fields a `Clob` or `NClob` should be used.

A binary representation in string should be used for `Blob` such as HEX or Base64.

For Oracle there are several stored procedure, or functions for this purpose, such as `rawtohex(COLUMN)`, `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(COLUMN))` and some other.